# How to ref nested ObjectId in mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my category schema where i have nested nestedCategorySchema and I want to refer to this ObjectId of this in other collection

`

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const nestedCategorySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  },
});

const categorySchema = new Schema(
  {
    clientname: {
      type: Schema.Types.String,
    },
    categoryOne: {
      type: [nestedCategorySchema],
      default: [],
    },
    categoryTwo: {
      type: [nestedCategorySchema],
      default: [],
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

exports.default = mongoose.model("category", categorySchema);

mongoose.model("category").collection.createIndex({
  clientname: 1,
});
```

`

In another collection I want to refer the nested categoryOne ObjectId

`

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const prodSchema = new Schema(
  {
    categories: [
      {
        _id: false,
        clientname: {
          type: String,
        },
**        categoryLevelOne: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "category.categoryOne",
        },**
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

`

In prodSchema I want to refer to nested categoryOne

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare the `nestedCategorySchema` as a model:

```
mongoose.model("nestedCategory", nestedCategorySchema);
```

And change the the `categoryOne` attribute in `categorySchema` to a `ObjectId` ref:

```
categoryOne: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'nestedCategory',
    default: []
}];
```

Finally, given your configuration, you should probably change the `categories` property in `prodSchema` to a ref itself:

```
const prodSchema = new Schema(
  {
    categories: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'category'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

In `mongoose` you can only create references to `ObjectId`s.

Comment: Hi @lpizzinidev Is there a way to do this without creating a new model

Comment: You need to create the `nestedCategory` model if you want to reference it. Since its property is just a name and the `prodSchema` reference the `category` model you could avoid creating it by declaring `categoryOne` as a string. But in that case, you would not store the values in a separate collection.